# Formula to return the latest running balance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that consists of three columns. they are

[image]

```
"IN" | "OUT" | "BALANCE"
```

IN - when i enter a numeric value in a row on this column, the "BALANCE" (which is actually a running balance) would get incremented by whatever the value entered under this column.

OUT - the same as IN except it decrements and updates the "BALANCE" Running Balance

What i am trying to figure out is:

I have a separate summary sheet which is supposed to show the latest running balance (only) as per the updated figures

The problems i have are:
1: how to retrieve the latest running balance?

2: The rows may extend as and when updated, it might grow from a single entry to 100's of entries (rows), in such a scenario how do i get the last updated running balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **bottom** value in column **C** of *Sheet1* use:

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,Sheet1!C:C)
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I did a few tweaks and it works now, just to clarify what does 99^99 mean also when i give the C:C it gives an error so i simply gave a range of rows ex: D2:D100 am i  doing it right? please advice

Comment: I did a few tweaks and it works now, just to clarify what does 99^99 mean also when i give the C:C it gives an error so i simply gave a range of rows ex: D2:D100 am i doing it right?

Comment: @Prem The **99^99** tries to find an impossibly large value, so it returns the last value instead.  The **C:C** will not work on versions of Excel earlier than Excel 2007.  The adjustments you made were perfect!  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

[First Response on Google](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/return-the-last-item-in-an-excel-column/) for "Formula to Return the Last Value in Column":

Assuming no blanks in column C:

```
=INDEX(C:C, COUNTA(C:C), 1)
```